# How to modify html document inside div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How I can modify HTML document inside my `div` in jQuery?

This is my code:

```js
$(".lastName").click(function() {
  val = $(".mydiv").clone();
  //then before to append the 'val' in result class, i want it first to modify the label text from 'First Name' to 'Last Name'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
  <label class="label">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="myinput">
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
<button class="lastName">Last Name</button
```

Comment: `$("yourElement").text()` . take a look at W3C: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/), but first get the node with `.find('.label')` and print in result `$('.result').html(val)`

```js
$(".lastName").click(function() {
  let val = $(".mydiv").clone();
  $(val).find('.label').html('Last Name');
  //then before to append the 'val' in result class, i want it first to modify the label text from 'First Name' to 'Last Name'
  $('.result').html(val)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
  <label class="label">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="myinput">
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
<button class="lastName">Last Name</button>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks man